# SQL update and group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table employees , with columns id_departament and salary like that :

```
salary    ID
10000     3
20000     3
8000      2
5000      1
24000     4
20000     1
5000      2
7500      4
```

I want to build a query to increase **ONLY** the max salary for every departament with 10% and if the salary after adding the 10% is higher than 25000 then my salary have to be 25 000 , in my example after adding 10% from max salary in departament 4 will increase from 24000 to 25000.

My code:

```
update angajati set salariul = case when salariul+10/100*salariul<25000 
then salariul+10/100*salariul else 25000
end where salariul = (select MAX(salariul) from angajati group by 
id_departament);
```

Until now I have this code , but I receive an error which says :

```
SQL Error: ORA-01427: 01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query returning more than one row

```
SELECT Max(salariul) 
FROM   angajati b 
GROUP BY id_departament
```

To fix it you need to `correlate` the `sub-query`

```
UPDATE angajati A
SET    salariul = CASE 
                    WHEN salariul + 10 / 100 * salariul < 25000 THEN 
                    salariul + 10 / 100 * 
                               salariul 
                    ELSE 25000 
                  END 
WHERE  salariul = (SELECT Max(salariul) 
                   FROM   angajati b 
                   WHERE  a.id_departament = b.id_departament);
```

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00904: "A"."ID_DEPARTAMENT":00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: check now there was a typo

Comment: in 3 minutes , i will be able to!